# Why the up-votes and down-votes does not sum up to reputation?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I know there are minor differences between votes sum and reputation, like the fact that no user can have negative reputation. However, the sum of the up/down-votes and bounties differ from the reputation very much (both positively and negatively), see [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/140248/approximate-recalculation-of-user-reputation).

What am I missing? Surely there are some other things in effect, but what would make changes in reputation as large as ten thousands?

**Edit:** Thank you all for suggestions, daily reputation cap was the thing that generated the biggest differences. An improved query can be found [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/140252/approximate-recalculation-of-user-reputation). Of course, if you would have some further suggestions, go ahead.

Comment: Community Wiki post? Bounty given? User suspensions? Accepted answers? There are so many things that isn't factored into the data explorer query that it isn't meaningful in anyway.

Comment: ... going over daily upvote-reputation limits, editing bonuses, accepting answers....

Comment: And also: reputation cap per day, which is likely to be a biggie for the [legendary users](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary).

Comment: @Arthur: Ahhh! We crossed the stream! Abort, abort!

Comment: And casting downvotes!  (Though the effect is small)

Comment: @Willie: Next time, when someone asks you if you're a god -- you say yes!